# JSONata: How to substitute . with _ in key names?

Tags: jsonata

Update: editing question to provide a multi-level object example:

```
{
  "An.Example": "Dots.are.okay.in.values",
  "Product": {
    "Product.ID.Number": 858383 ,
    "Product.Name": "Bowler Hat",
    "Unit.Cost": 12
  }
}
```

Exerciser: https://try.jsonata.org/ZdaDTJFMA

---

[original question]
Hello JSONata newbie checking in again. Given this source which I'm keeping very simple for the purposes of this example...

```
{
  "Product.Name": "Bowler Hat",
  "Product.ID.Number": 858383
}
```

How can I transform any "." in key names to "_"? The key names will not be known in advance so I can't simply hard code. Desired result:

```
{
  "Product_Name": "Bowler Hat",
  "Product_ID_Number": 858383
}
```

I took a look at the example shown here -- https://try.jsonata.org/ry9G5Xr3H -- which was in response to this question -- [Find fields which contains a text and replace it with another text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982136/find-fields-which-contains-a-text-and-replace-it-with-another-text) -- but cannot come up w/ the proper adjustments to address my need.

Sample JSON and non-working code here -- https://try.jsonata.org/uOwYJOLto

Thank you in advance for any assistance or suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$each(function($v, $k) {
    { $replace($k, '.', '_'): $v}
}) ~> $merge()
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/uZgm69Bfy

If you want to traverse a hierarchy of objects, then you'll need write a recursive function:

```
(
    $dotsToUnderscores := $each(?, function($v, $k) {
        { $replace($k, '.', '_'): $type($v) = 'object' ? $dotsToUnderscores($v) : $v}
    }) ~> $merge;
    $dotsToUnderscores($)
)
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/WsfsFGhjE or https://try.jsonata.org/r2GrHYYou

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Andrew, I appreciate the answer... unfortunately it doesn't work with sub-objects. I will update the question with a multi-level example. TIA for any additional help.

Comment: Hoping for a solution that will replace within keys at any level of object depth. TIA.